# python 2.7 under windows: cannot import ui_mainwindow

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

I have python 2.7 under windows x64, I have been trying to make a simple GUI using PyQt4, like this:
from PyQt4 import *
from ui_mainwindow import Ui_MainWindow

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):

when I run the program I have this error:  " No module named ui_mainWindow"
-I have pyqt4 installed
- I have tried to replace um_mainwindow with ui_simple and clientGUI but the same error resulted.
What am I doing wrong and how to fix this?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, ui_mainWindow is a python file generated by some Qt Tool, that transforms .ui file from QtDesigner to Python class.
I have no real experience with PyQT, but I know both C++/Qt and python. In C++/Qt QtCreator does the job of transforming .ui file to C++ class, but probably in python You need to do this Yourself.